# How can I configure DHCP server to issue the same fixed-address by matching with the client identifier in the discover message

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server, isc-dhcp, dhcpd, dhcp-option

I am able to config fixed ip address with hardware ethernet options, but i am trying to assign fixed ip based on client id(option 61) from DISCOVER message. I tried with below configs , but it doesn't help.

```
host virtual_1
{
      dhcp-client-identifier = 00:00:00:00:01
      option routers 10.1.1.49;
      option host-name "virtual1";
      #hardware ethernet 00:01:02:03:04:05;
      fixed-address 10.1.1.179;
      option ntp-servers  10.1.1.49; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the syntax wrong.
Here is how I do it (based on a readable client id)

```
host aaa {
    option dhcp-client-identifier = "XYZ-aaa";
    fixed-address 123.123.123.123;
}
```

The "aaa" and "XYZ-aaa" are arbitrary -- you choose;
I use dhclient, so I have:

```
send dhcp-client-identifier "XYZ-aaa";
```

in the /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf file